# How to change the solidity code style in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, vscode-extensions

I am going to change the Solidity code style in Visual Studio Code.
I have already installed the Solidity plugin.
When I press SHIFT + ALT + F, it hasn't any actions, but it should have correct style.

Comment: What extension for solidity do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure Solidity Extension is Enabled: Double-check that the Solidity extension is properly installed and enabled. Sometimes, extensions can be disabled accidentally.
2. Check for Conflicts: If you have multiple formatters for Solidity or similar languages installed, they might conflict. Go to the Extensions tab, search for any other Solidity-related extensions you have installed, and temporarily disable them to see if that resolves the issue.
3. Configure Default Formatter: Sometimes, VSCode does not automatically set the installed Solidity extension as the default formatter for .sol files. You can specify it manually:
   •   Open a .sol file.
   •   Right-click on the document.
   •   Click “Format Document With…”.
   •   Then select “Configure Default Formatter…”.
   •   Choose the Solidity extension from the list.
4. Edit Settings.json: You can manually add configuration to your settings.json file to ensure VSCode uses the Solidity formatter.
   •   Open Command Palette with Ctrl+Shift+P.
   •   Type Preferences: Open Settings (JSON) and press Enter.
5. Check for Updates: Ensure both VSCode and the Solidity extension are up to date. Sometimes, bugs related to formatting are fixed in newer versions.
6. Restart VSCode: After making changes to settings or extensions, it’s a good idea to restart VSCode to ensure all changes take effect properly.
7. Check the Keyboard Shortcut: Go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and search for Format Document. Ensure it is set to SHIFT + ALT + F. If not, you can set it manually.

If none of these steps work, consider looking for any open issues on the Solidity extension’s GitHub page or reaching out for support there. Sometimes, specific bugs or compatibility issues with certain versions of VSCode or the extension itself can cause such behavior, and the maintainers or community might have workarounds.